# Need to calculate last 5 value average from today's date using only work days (weekdays Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri) using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to show a rolling average of pieces produced from the last 5 work days.

Currently I am tracking all days Mon-Sun and taking the last 5 days.

Here is my current formula:

```
=SUMIFS(AL:AL,AK:AK,">="&TODAY()-5,AL:AL,"<="&TODAY())/5
```

With AL:AL being the date column and AK:AK being the pieces produced.

I Can't figure how to arrange the data and dates to get my last 5 days average.

Answer (score 0):

This is not difficult with a helper column.  As you indicated in the question, the arrangement **is** important.  First, organize your data with the **most recent values at the top.**  So **AL1** will always hold today's date.

In **AM1** enter:

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(AL1)=1,WEEKDAY(AL1)=7),"",1)
```

In **AM2** enter:

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(AL2)=1,WEEKDAY(AL2)=7),"",IF(SUM(AM$1:AM1)=5,"",1))
```

*(column **AM** defines the values to be averages)*

Then in another cell enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(AM1:AM10=1)*(AK1:AK10))/5
```

[image]

Some beginners place the most recent data at the bottom of a column.  This usually make it more difficult to analyze.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This does and will help me out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `SUMIFS()` function is incorrectly reproduced. The first argument is the "sum_range," the data to be summed, so that should be the number of pieces.

Also, you are getting 6 days including today. If you want 5 days (and if you have data for today), then you have to subtract 4 instead of 5.

You can accomplish what you want with this formula, I think:

```
=SUMIFS(AK:AK,AL:AL,">="&WORKDAY(TODAY(),-4),AK:AK,"<="&TODAY())/5
```

If you don't actually have data for today, then subtract 5 instead of 4.

This also depends entirely on your not having any data for weekend days. If you have production data for weekend days, then the averages will be off (they will include extra days).

If you have data for both weekdays and weekend days, you will have to use something like @garysstudent suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the value add. The correction to my formula helped me get what I was looking for.